# How to replace slice of array in Swift?

Tags: swift

To replace a slice of array in Swift, we can use subscript assignment or `replaceSubrange` method on array. But, I wonder how can I change the elements of named subrange so that original array change as well?

```swift
var array = Array(0..<10)
var slice = array[0..<3]
slice[...] = [-1,-1,-1]
print(slice) // [-1, -1, -1]
print(array) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] does not change
```

Comment: `slice` is a copy not a reference. If you want to edit your array in place you could do something like `array[0..<3] = [-1,-1,-1]` or `array[0..<3] = slice`.

Comment: Yes, I know that option as I stated in question. I am looking for a way to do it with a ArraySlice variable.

Comment: @BarışDenizSağlam, there isn't such a way. ArraySlice should be thought of as a copy - not a reference - to the subsection of the original array. Under the covers, it uses copy-on-write technique to only copy when something is being mutated, and uses the same memory for reading